# Linear Programming question on Fantasy premier league fixtures List

Tags: python, pulp

My objective is:

1. to find which teams have the easiest game for each game week
2. to select 2 teams max in the solution (by permuting score from those 2 teams for each game week)

my data set looks like this:
[image: data set]

event (1) being the first week game, event (2) the second week game etc...

I am currently able to select the best game for each fixture using:

```
for event_id in np.unique(events):
    model += sum(decisions[i] for i in range(event) if events[i]==event_id) == 1  # pick one fixture for each game week
```

Bu i do not know how to build a constraint asking the model to pick only 2 teams for the season and managing the permutation. I have tried a few things with no success.

my LP function is as follow:

```py
def fixtures_analyser(team, events, expected_scores):
    
    event = len(events)
    objFunction=pulp.LpMaximize
    model = pulp.LpProblem("Constrained value maximisation", objFunction)
    decisions = [
        pulp.LpVariable("x{}".format(i), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')
        for i in range(event)
    ]
    
     # objective function:
    model += sum((decisions[i]) * (float(expected_scores[i]))
        for i in range(event)), "Objective"

     # event constraint
    for event_id in np.unique(events):
        model += sum(decisions[i] for i in range(event) if events[i]==event_id) == 1  # total cost

    model.solve()
    print("Total expected score = {}".format(model.objective.value()))

    return decisions
```

Output is currently like this:
[image: Current Output]

Expected outcome would be to see only 2 teams e.g. Liverpool and Man city and not chelsea etc..

Comment: Your problem isn't fully clear to me. I understand you want the teams with the best odds throughout the season. To me that would be the teams with the best *sum of `expected_score`*. However, by taking one match every round, if those teams don't play against each other, what do you get then? Does it become the team that has the highest `expected_score` the most often? That's also fine. Also, what happens when away teams are the favourite? Does the expected score become negative them?

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for your reply. I need to select 4 defenders in my team, the 4 defenders should come from only 2 teams. I want to be able to rotate them each week depending on which team has the better odds for their own fixture. This is why i am checking the max expected score from each fixture and for each gameweek and not taking the sum of all weeks combined. The sum should be the sum of max expected_score from my pair (team1, team2) for each gameweek. This is where i am stuck, my script works currently but take every team and not just 2.

Comment: The sum of the max expected score between those two teams? Like team A has 100 ES, team B has 20 ES, and team C has 150 ES (but worse in other games). Do I take 100 or 150, or maybe 0 because neither of the two teams has the max expected score? And what if the teams play each other?